# Managed Service Identity configuration for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

Trying to connect to Azure Data Lake storage Gen2 using MSI (Azure Managed Identity) via Hadoop client in console and receive the error
`ls: AADToken: HTTP connection failed for getting token from AzureAD. Http response: 400 Bad Request*`

Connection via Shared Key works fine.

What was done:

1. Created a Windows 10 VM in Azure and installed Haddop client 3.2 from Apache site and JRE 1.8.0
2. Created Storage account using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-quickstart-create-account
3. Created Azure AD application using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal
4. Turned on System-assigned managed identity for VM as described here 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm
5. Assigned a managed identity access to the Storage account as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-portal

To connect using a command below:

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.azure.ssl.channel.mode=Default_JSSE -Dfs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.MsiTokenProvider -Dfs.azure.account.auth.type=OAuth -Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.msi.tenant=<tenant_ID> -Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id=<Client_ID> -ls abfss://<filesystem_name>2@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

Something wrong or missed? Please advice.

Thank you!

Comment: If you use the MSI(System-assigned managed identity) to access the adls gen2, what is the AD App in the step 3 used to do?

Comment: As far as I know to create a client ID.

Comment: No need to do that, if you enable the MSI of the VM, it will create a service principal in your tenant automatically, it is the same name of your VM, it has its own client id. You can find it in the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> Enterprise applications-> search with your VM name(filter with `All Applications`), refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wotcb.png. The application id(client id) is that you want. If you use that client id, will it work?

Comment: At least the output has changed ```ls: GET https://<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filesystem_name>?resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&timeout=90&recursive=false``` and nothing else however the container is not empty

Comment: In the step 5, did you give the MSI a `Storage Blob Data Owner` role?

Comment: It Works! Thank you a lot. The role was Contributor, I change it to Storage Blob Data Owner and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JoyWang if I use the same approach for User-Assigned managed identity will it work or do I need some additional property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add my comment as an answer:

No need to do the step 3, if you enable the MSI of the VM, it will create a service principal in your tenant automatically, it is the same name of your VM, it has its own client id. You can find it in the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> Enterprise applications-> search with your VM name(filter with `All Applications`).

In the step 5, you need to give the MSI a `Storage Blob Data Owner` role.